# Should I ever return a list that was passed by reference and modified?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have recently discovered that lists in python are automatically passed by reference (unless the notation array[:] is used). For example, these two functions do the same thing:

```
def foo(z):
    z.append(3)

def bar(z):
    z.append(3)
    return z

x = [1, 2]
y = [1, 2]
foo(x)
bar(y)
print(x, y)
```

Before now, I always returned arrays that I manipulated, because I thought I had to. Now, I understand it's superfluous (and perhaps inefficient), but it seems like returning values is generally good practice for code readability. My question is, are there any issues for doing either of these methods/ what are the best practices? Is there a third option that I am missing? I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything that really answers my question.

Comment: "automatically passed by reference" Technically this is incorrect. Python passes things around with copies of references. These references may be to a mutable or an immutable object, and this is where the confusion comes from. See http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html

Comment: @DeepSpace. That, and "by reference" and "by value" are simply not the only available options.

Comment: The "pythonic" way-- if you are writing a function that changes the `list`-- is to not return anything (unless you have a really good reason to do so). Instead, specifically say in the function docstring that the function modifies the `list`. Also, python passes objects neither by value NOR by reference, and you need to [read this article](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/).

Comment: Is this just a toy example, or are you actually writing a function that modifies a `list`? If so, why do you believe you need to do that?

Comment: @RickTeachey. It's just a toy example, but I do write functions that modify lists. As far as I know, one can either 1. modify a list within a function (which after reading the answers here should never also return for readability), or 2. create a copy of a list and return that. I've heard the former is a cheaper operation, which makes me think that it would be better in most cases.

Comment: @MichaelSkarn ehhh.... not copying is DEFINITELY far cheaper, but if your dseign choices are being made based on THAT, i'm wondering what it is you are writing that is so unmoored from things, you are so easily able to choose whether to modify the list or not. usually in my code, i have found that deciding whether or not to treat a list as a thing to be modified is determined more by the problem itself. but i'm not a pro developer so what do i know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer works on the assumption that the decision as to whether to modify your input in-place or return a copy has already been made.

As you noted, whether or not to return a modified object is a matter of opinion, since the result is functionally equivalent. In general, it is considered good form to *not* return a list that is modified in-place. According to the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (item #2):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

This is borne out in the standard library. List methods are notorious for this on SO: [`list.append`, `insert`, `extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), etc.

Numpy also uses this pattern frequently, since it often deals with large data sets that would be impractical to copy and return. A common example is the array method [`numpy.ndarray.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html), not to be confused with the top-level function [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), which returns a new copy.

The idea is something that is very much a part of the Python way of thinking. Here is an excerpt from [Guido's email](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html) that explains the whys and wherefors:

> I find the chaining form a threat to readability; it requires that the reader must be intimately familiar with each of the methods.  The second [unchained] form makes it clear that each of these calls acts on the same object, and so even if you don't know the class and its methods very well, you can understand that the second and third call are applied to x (and that all calls are made for their side-effects), and not to something else.

Comment: which helps to fight notorious method chaining antipattern :)

Comment: On the other hand, it can also be good form to return a modified _copy_ of the list. Which form is better for a given function depends on the function and context.

Comment: @Serge Method chaining isn't an antipattern on its own, but there is a time and place for it, and it shouldn't be misused in other places (such as appending to a list).

Comment: @jirassimok. OP is specifically describing the in-place situation. If you are dealing with copies, you pretty much have to return the copy.

Comment: I could have phrased that comment better. I was basically trying to clarify that there are times when you want to make a modified copy instead of modifying the input, which I didn't want to add as a separate answer because it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @jirassimok. I've sort-of addressed that in my update.

Comment: I like the update quite a bit, especially the reference to the Zen of Python. I'd upvote it, but I already did.

Answer (score 1):

The "best practice" is technically to not modify the thing at all:

```
def baz(z):
    return z + [3]

x = [1, 2]
y = baz(x)
print(x, y)
```

but in general it's clearer if you restrict yourself to either returning a new object or modifying an object in-place, but not both at once.

There are examples in the standard library that both modify an object in-place and return *something* (the foremost example being `list.pop()`), but that's a special case because it's not returning *the object that was modified*.

Comment: Wouldn't modifying the original list be a faster than making a copy though? Or is the difference negligible?

Comment: @MichaelSkarn Yes, and more memory efficient, but also people might still want the original list for some reason (you'll notice that almost every method of the `str` class returns a new, changed instance rather than modifying the string itself).

Comment: @MichaelSkarn. Really depends on how big the list is, and what the modification is. `x[0] = 3` on a list with 10**6 elements is probably cheaper than making a new one. Calling `append` won't make a difference if the buffer has to be reallocated either way (which doesn't always happen because of amortization).

Answer (score 1):

Python built-ins, as a rule, will not do both, to avoid confusion over whether the function/method modifies its argument in place or returns a new value. When modifying in place, no `return` is performed (making it implicitly return `None`). The exceptions are cases where a mutating function returns something other than the object mutated (e.g. `dict.pop`, `dict.setdefault`).

It's generally a good idea to follow the same pattern, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There's not strict *should* of course, However, a function [should either *do something*, or *return something*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). So, you'd better either modify the list in place without returning anything, or return a new one, leaving the original one unchanged.

> Note: the list is not exactly *passed by reference*. It's the *value of the reference* that is actually passed. Keep that in mind if you re-assign